# what is the best way to send xml string over java Sockets?

Tags: java, xml, sockets, jaxb, bufferedreader

I tried this, but somewhere along the line I can't read the response from the server. (The response is in XML).

I have read that writing over sockets requires buffering due to the string breakage. Somehow I discovered this is true when I used a jaxb unmarshaller and it reported a SAX EOF exception, meaning the xml been read was not complete.

Please how do I buffer write and buffer read properly?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<estel>");
sb.append("<header><requesttype>").append(hd.getRequestType()).append("</requesttype></header>");
sb.append("<request>");
sb.append("<agentcode>").append(rq.getAgentCode()).append("</agentcode>");
sb.append("<pin>").append(rq.getPin()).append("</pin>");
sb.append("<destination>").append(rq.getDestination()).append("</destination>");
sb.append("<agenttransid>").append(rq.getAgentTransId()).append("</agenttransid>");
sb.append("<vendorcode>").append(rq.getVendorCode()).append("</vendorcode>");
sb.append("<amount>").append(rq.getAmount()).append("</amount>");
    sb.append("<productcode>").append(rq.getProductCode()).append("</productcode>");
    sb.append("<comments>").append(rq.getComments()).append("</comments>");
    sb.append("<clienttype>").append(rq.getClientType()).append("</clienttype>");
sb.append("</request></estel>");


    Socket socket = new Socket("41.206.23.21",7101);
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

    OutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(os);    
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(buf);

    System.out.printf("\nxml is %s",sb.toString());   
   System.out.print("\n--------writing--to--socket-----");
    out.write(sb.toString());
    out.flush();

    //read response
    InputStream bui = new BufferedInputStream(in);
  rd = new InputStreamReader(bui);
   System.out.print("\nxml response"+rd.toString());

   in.close();
   out.close();
   socket.close();
```

Comment: What you say is merely true for HTTP POST requests. Plain sockets have a straight forward behavior.

Comment: Your code suffers from the common misunderstanding that there are 'messages' in TCP. There are not - there is just a stream of bytes. Thus there's no clear way for the recipient of your write-to-socket to know when it's received the last byte intended (unless it's parsing as it goes, so it can delay until it has got the `</estel>` that matches the initial `<estel>`, but I doubt you're doing that). If you want messages, you have to invent a protocol to delimit them. Ending the output stream after the write (before awaiting the response) would be one way.

Answer (score 0):

You send the XML over the socket but the server side does not answer. To be 100% sure what happens, we would need the server code and server error messages. So far I see two things, you could do:

1. When writing and flushing the XML, you can call `socket.shutdownOutput()`. This sends an EOF to the server, indicating that there's nothing more to read. Latest than the server should know, that it has to work on the XML and produce the result.
2. You send a String of `char` over a Stream of `byte`. Hopefully the server understands that in the same way as the client sends it. As hope is not really helpful in programming, you should wrap the output stream like this: `Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.shutdownOutput(), "UTF-8");` and do the write and the flush with the writer. Notice that you need to do the same on the server side for the input stream (wrap as Reader with "UTF-8")

Comment: is socket.shutDownOutput() compulsory for xml?> i thought so because that kind of stabilizes the program but i cant seem to read what im writing from the response. still isnt resolved

Comment: The way you transport the text (here via sockets) has nothing to do with what you transport (here a XML document). As I said, when the server is not responding to your XML, than the server hangs. Most likely because the server is still waiting for more input or did not recognize, that the XML ended. That's why I suggest to send an EOF over the ouput stream. BUT, as we have no information about the server, it might be any other issue. If you need more help you need to provide more information about the server.

Comment: Say the response string is <estel><header><request>invalid request <\request><\header><\estel> when I telnet, then using socket and unmarshalling with jaxb I also get this response , you get this response only when you dont send the proper xml format

Comment: You get this response simply because the XML parser throws an exception on the server. In your case, the same parser tries to read further as it did not receive an EOF. HAve you tried to send the EOF with `socket.shutdownOutput()`?

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce your issue to a running piece of code that shows the error. Posting some code that does not even compile, does not really help in understanding the problem you have. Even after fitting this code in a method and importing java.io stuff, there is 4 (!) undeclared variables: `hd, rq, out and rd`.

To help with your problem and answer your questions:

1. You do not need to use a buffered writer, you just have to make sure you write everything you want to write (and flush or close the stream afterwards). The client (receiver) of course has to read from that stream as long as bytes are available before he tries to interpret the data.
2. If you want to implement a different protocol, you of course have to read / write until a certain marker or whatever indicates that your transmission is finished. For this question however I assume you only want to transmit one set of XML data.

For writing you can simply write the String in one go using a simple `OutputStream`.
Code like this would do the job:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//...
Socket socket = new Socket("41.206.23.21", 7101);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();
```

Reading that, you can also use a simple `InputStream`. To make sure you get everything, you should usually read the data and write it all to an intermediate byte array which you then can transform back into your String. A generic method for doing that, could be like this:

```
  String read(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int got;
    while ((got = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, got);
    }
    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    String result = new String(data);
    return result;
  }
```

Keep in mind that this method neither closes the stream, nor handles exceptions.

Comment: @Matthiaas i actually tried your version but it hangs @ the point where writing to socket begins, the whole code is within a try block and a IOException catches it.

Comment: At which point? You do it in two programs or at least in two threads, yes?

Comment: I'm simply writing the code in one class with a main method and a try block encapsulates the reading outputstream and inputstream, it seems for xml strings u actualli nid to do socket.shutDownOutput().  For it to stop hanging ,seems the server is expecting more data .